# Android cpu frequency not sticking

Tags: android, cpu

I have developed an app that modifies the frequency of the CPU. My app worked very fine with my Nexus 4 Lollipop, I can turn on/off cores, modifies the frequency of each one, etc. But now I have switched to my Nexus 6 Nougat, and it is not allowing me to decrease the frequency to a certain level, for example:

(The governor is userspace)

These are the possible frequencies:

300000 422400 652800 729600 883200 960000 1036800 1190400 1267200 1497600 1574400 1728000 1958400 2265600 2457600 2496000 2572800 2649600

If I try to echo any frequency below '1497600' my cellphone automatically raise this frequency back to '1497600', but ANY speed above this level will sticky normally. I've tried to stop mpdecision, and after that rename it, but no changes. Is there any way to know if mpdecision has stopped? Is the new Android not allowing me to change these values?

```
private void writeSpeedOnCore(int core,int speed){
        StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();
        //Turn on Core if it is offline
        if(speed!=0) {
            if(currentClockLevel[core][2]==0) {
                turnCoreOnOff(core, true);
            }
            adjustMinAndMaxSpeed(core);
            try {
                path.setLength(0);
                path.append(String.format("echo %d" + " > " + pathCPU + core + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed", speed));
                Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", path.toString()});
                proc.waitFor();
                currentClockLevel[core][0] = speed;
            } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
            turnCoreOnOff(core,false);
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code so that we can help you debug.

Comment: Actually the problem its not the code since I can change the frequency and it works perfectly fine on my nexus 4, but when I touch the screen the system raise it up to 1497600. I will post the function anyway.

Comment: You can see if mpdecision is running by using ps:
`adb shell ps | grep mpdecision`